# Make IPs anonymous in output of Web analytics tool - perl or sed?

Tags: perl, replace, sed, ip

I analysed logs with http://www.w3perl.com/, now i want the IPs made anonymous.

So i want them changed in all html-files in the whole directory.

1. I thought about just always turning the third and fourth octet into the same number for all IPs. But i read something about XOR-ing them - what is that about?
2. what is the better way to manage the replacing and why? sed or perl or another option?

I am pretty new to this, i hope i searched the other topics enough. I haven't found anything related to my problem. 
Thanks in advance and please excuse my English.
This website is just great - i've learned so much in the last days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masking IP-Address can be better achieved with `perl`. You can take a look [here](https://metacpan.org/search?q=ip%20address) for using already available modules so that you won't have to re-invent the wheel. Unfortunately I don't know `perl`, so I can only offer `sed` solution.

You can use something like this for replacing all ip-address in your file.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/**masked ip**/g' < yourfile > newfile
```

---

**Your file:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat fmp
this is 12.34.55.222 and 
21.3.34.5
also there is 133.42.55.23
```

**Step 1: Identify IP-Addresses:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/**&**/g' fmp
this is **12.34.55.222** and 
**21.3.34.5**
also there is **133.42.55.23**
```

**Step 2: Replace IP-Address with your mask**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/**&**/g' fmp | sed '/\*\*.*\\*\*/s//**masked ip**/'
this is **masked ip** and 
**masked ip**
also there is **masked ip**
```

You can either make `sed -i` *(in-line)* substitution or use `>` to re-direct your output to another file.

---

Obviously this can be reduced to the following. The above would be useful for debugging as you can view what is being changed before making the change.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/** masked ip **/g' fmp
this is ** masked ip ** and 
** masked ip **
also there is ** masked ip **
```

Good Luck!!

**Update:**

As posted by **Mark** in the `comments`, a `perl` variant would be -

```
perl -pe 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/** masked ip **/g' < inputfile > outputfile
```

**Update II:**

As requested by OP, the following one-liner will find the files and perform the substitution.

```
find /path/to/dir/ -type f -name "*.html" -exec perl -ibak -pe 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/** masked ip **/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I am new to sed (just used Perl) - time to change that ;)

Comment: No worries, if you do have any questions feel free to ask them and I will update my answer to include them. :)

Comment: With perl this would be: ```perl -pe 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/** masked ip **/g' < fmp```.

Comment: Thanks @markijbema. I have added your solution in the answer. Hope thats ok.

Comment: Wow! Thanks again! Is there a simple trick to make perl-one-liner run through all files in a directory?

Comment: You can do `find /path/to/dir/ -type f -name "*.html" -exec perl -ibak -pe 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/** masked ip **/g' {} \;` This will make in-file changes and will make a backup of all your files just be on the safer side. You can change just run find command to see what files are fetched. If they all look ok then you can add in the exec portion of the code.

Comment: Hi there! I get the right files with find, but the replacing won't work. bak and original files do not differ.
I saw in another Thread to put {} in single quotes, but that didn't work either.

Comment: With `-i` option your original files should have been modified. I tried on my system and it worked fine. Try running the `perl` or `sed` command without `find` simply by passing in 1 file and see if it is able to make changes in that. Regards to the other question you can either quote the `{}` or put `\;`. Both serves the same purpose.

Comment: First: i appreciate your patience with a total beginner like me! Now to the check:

sed works just fine, perl does not

Comment: No worries at all. Add `sed` code to your `exec` and see if that works.

Comment: Just did that and it just what i needed. Thank you all very much!
I should learn how to use sed. Any recommendations for a beginner besides the manpages?

Comment: I am not too fond of `sed` but you can refer [this](http://sed.sourceforge.net/) and [this](http://www.pement.org/sed/) and [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/). Don't forget to mark the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the links! May i ask why you are not fond of it? It is a basic tool and available on all Unix/Linux-Systems, right? And it did the job  ;) Not that good-looking with all the escaped characters perhaps?

Comment: `sed` is good for quick fixes. But as you try and attempt to solve complex problems it gets messier and difficult to follow. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8571422/970195) answer and try figuring out what `sed` does. :)